# splash screen on iphone device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, splash-screen

i m getting the splash screen on the iphone device even after removing the Default.png.if i m to run  my app on my device. i m still getting the splash screen and it remains frozen. i m not able to get into my application..cud u guys help me out

Comment: it works fine in iphone simulator...the problem is if i m to run my app in the device.....i m getting only the splash screen

Comment: Open organizer and see the console when you try to build on the phone.

Comment: @terente:i opened the console..at the bottom of screen i m getting:ERROR from Debugger:The program being debugged is not being run

Comment: Delete the app from the iPhone, in xcode do an clean for the project from Products menu -> Clean and then rebuild

Comment: were to find the Products menu... i m a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the app from the iPhone, in xcode do an clean for the project from Products menu -> Clean and then rebuild